# not all arguments converted during string formatting - Python

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
def rndint(self, s=0, l=10):
    num = pow(self._seed, 2)
    strnum = str(num)
    if len(strnum) < 3:
        strnum + "37"
    mid = int(strnum[1:len(strnum)-1]) % l+1
    self._seed = mid
    return mid
```

The problem is, when I run it with:

```
rnd = Random(100)
rnd.rndint()
```

It gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3066, in run_code
        exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-29-0d460ce98561>", line 1, in <module>
        rnd.rndint()
    File "C:\Users\Anshul\PycharmProjects\AMath\amath\random\randomGen.py", line 16, in rndint
        mid = int(strnum[1:len(strnum)-1]) % l+1
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: For start, `strnum + "37"` should probably be replaced by `strnum += "37"`.

Comment: I don't get the same error when I run the same code, though, and neither should it give that error, since the code you posted explicitly does integer conversion. Are you really sure you're actually running the code you posted?

Comment: For example, I assume you're running this in an interactive Python shell (as indicated by your stacktrace); isn't it just that you haven't either restarted the shell or reloaded the code after editing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that python thinks you are trying to do string substitution, when you are intending to actually use the modulus operator. Perhaps try using parentheses around `l + 1` like `%(l+1)`?  Not sure if that will work, but that's the only thing that seems to explain your error.

Also, I think you mean to have the line above it say:

```
if len(strnum) < 3:
    strnum += "37"
```

That also might be causing the error.  Otherwise the line above it is doing nothing.

Also, this may help:

```
mid = int(strnum[1:-1])%(l+1)
```

Let me know if anything works.